# Change rows into columns in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have one dataset

```
sn   Name   Feature  score
1    pen-1     cost      2
2    pen-1     color     3
3    pen-1     look      1
4    pen-2     cost      1
5    pen-2     color     2
6    pen-2     look      4
```

I want to change it to the below format

```
sn  Name    Cost Look color
 1  Pen-1    2    1    3 
 2  pen-2    1    4    2
```

Please Solve My problem using `R` Programming. Thanks

Comment: Your `sn` column in the result doesn't make sense. Why should it be `1, 2`? Why not `1,4`? Both `sn:1` and `sn:2` are associated with `pen-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df1, Name~Feature, value.var="score")
```

Or `spread` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df1[-1], Feature, score)
#   Name color cost look
#1 pen-1     3    2    1
#2 pen-2     2    1    4
```